# Does the 2014 13inch vs 15inch Macbook Pro Make A Difference?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, mac

I'm currently a Design Comms student and I'm thinking of changing my 2012 macbook pro to the new 2014 retina macbook pro. I'm torn between the choice of the 13inch high end model of it's kind or the 15inch low end model (The one without the graphics card.). Which one should I get? And will it make a big difference?

Comment: Probably not an appropriate question for this exchange as these types of questions elicit opinions rather than fact-based answers.

Comment: No one here can really state what is best *for you*. We don't really know you, your needs, or your work habits.

Answer (score 1):

Fact-based answer: If it has been awkward with fitting more than one window on your current screen, then get the larger one. It will give you a psychological boost that things have improved.